# Have the geom_text just above the bar

Tags: r, bar-chart, categorical-data

This is my code

```
sur %>% 
  ggplot(aes(y =fct_infreq(no_lifetime_bite)))+ 
  geom_bar()+
  ylab("No of bites")+
  xlab("Body part")+
  ggtitle ("Anatomical sites of animal bites")+
  stat_count(geom = "text",
             aes(label=stat(count)),
             position=position_fill(vjust=2) )
```

I need to get the count of each bar just above the bar. In the picture of my plot attached here in this question, the counts are within the bar. How do I make it that my counts are automatically adjusted a bit above the bar?

[My plot with the counts that I need to change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wA6Aa.png)

Don't know how to do this.

Comment: Have you looked at utilizing position dodge? position=position_dodge(width=0.9), vjust=-0.25). I just gave random numbers for width and vjust but try playing around with that.

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput`?

Comment: levels = c("", "1", 
"2", "3", "Don't remember but multiple bites", "more than 5"), class = "factor")